# Windows-7 switching applications between displays

Tags: windows-7

I have a multi display setup on windows 7 where one display is a projector which is not constantly running. In XP when I had a window on the projector display (say firefox) and the projector was powered off all I did was right click firefox on the task bar select "Move" and blindly drag it over to my main display. However it seems the move option is gone on Windows 7, is there another easy way to get the window to come over to the main display?

Turning on the projector for a couple seconds is a waste and having to switch my display settings all the time is a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The move option is still there on Windows 7. If you have window previews on you need to scroll over the icon for the application on the taskbar, wait for the window preview to pop-up, and then right click in the preview and click 'Move'.

Answer (score 1):

Today I found out by accident that you can easily move the focused window between displays with the key combo <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>.